# javascript infovis sunburst - how to space nodes

Tags: javascript, infovis

I'm using this sunburst visualisation

[Sunburst example](https://jsbin.com/belefu/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

and trying to find a way to increase the width (or border width) between the adjacent nodes (shown in the image below as the thin black line separating the nodes "Coordinates" from "Core"

[image]

The document on configuring the sunburst is here
[Sunburst docs](https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Visualizations/Sunburst-js.html)
but I can't see a way to access this property.

Here is an example of the node config:

```
       Node: {
      overridable: true,
      type: 'multipie',
      align: "center",
      angularWidth: 20,
      lineWidth: 20,
      autoWidth: false
    },
```

Comment: Link isn’t working for me.

Comment: I am not sure but I think this is what you are looking for: https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Options/Options-Edge-js.html#Options.Edge unless they meant something else with `Edge`. You also have the option to create your very own line type it appears: https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Visualizations/Sunburst-js.html#Sunburst.Plot.EdgeTypes

Comment: Thanks Rens but the Edges option relates to lines connecting nodes - not the border around the node

Comment: Ok, in that case I couldn't really find anything other settings to modify. I think you'd have to dig into the source code to find out, or ask on github. GL :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to access the jit.js library and under the sunburst 'multipie' config, ie:

```
'multipie': {
  'render': function(node, canvas) {
    var height = node.getData('height');
    var ldist = height? height : this.config.levelDistance;
    var span = node.getData('span') / 2, theta = node.pos.theta;
    var begin = theta - span, end = theta + span;
    var polarNode = node.pos.getp(true);
    var polar = new Polar(begin, polarNode.rho);
    var p1coord = polar.getc(true);
    polar.theta = end;
    var p2coord = polar.getc(true);
    polar.rho += ldist;
    var p3coord = polar.getc(true);
    polar.theta = begin;
    var p4coord = polar.getc(true);
    var ctx = canvas.getCtx();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, polarNode.rho, begin, end, false);
    ctx.arc(0, 0, polarNode.rho + ldist, end, begin, true);
    ctx.moveTo(p1coord.x, p1coord.y);
    ctx.lineTo(p4coord.x, p4coord.y);
    ctx.moveTo(p2coord.x, p2coord.y);
    ctx.lineTo(p3coord.x, p3coord.y);
    ctx.fill();
```

I added the following:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.96)";
ctx.lineWidth   = 0.5;
ctx.save();
ctx.clip();
ctx.lineWidth *= 2;
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

The width and color of the stroke is set by **ctx.lineWidth** and **ctx.strokeStyle**

Can someone suggest a way of doing this without accessing the library?